# HealthKit - Does Source Queries return an App when user Did Not Allowed access or turned all Categories Off?

Tags: ios, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I will check if our Users have certain App installed.

If they do:

I want to know if they have allowed Access to HealthKit (if possible to know allowed categories)

So, **what does a Source Query returns if an App has been allowed or denied access?** What if the app is not installed?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine the HealthKit authorization status of other apps installed on the user's phone. An HKSourceQuery simply returns the sources of apps that have saved samples matching the given predicate, regardless of their authorization status or whether the app is currently installed.